# Open text message with an empty number

Tags: html

**GOAL:** Open text message with an empty number and filled with body text

Currently, I have a `/` in my `a` tag because leaving `sms:&body=.......` doesn't open an empty text message

When I click on:

```
<a href={`sms:/&body=Hey! I just created ${input}`}>
  Invite
</a>
```

My text message opens with a slash.

[image]

How can I open it up EMPTY?

This does not work:

```
<a href={`sms:&body=Hey! I just created ${input}`}>
  Invite
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```html
<a href={`sms:+&body=Hey! I just created ${input}`}>
  Invite
</a>
```

just doing the `+` opens my messages with no number in the recipients. Hopefully, you already figured this out. Goodluck!

**Update**

If you have issues with this try using the character URL encode for a blank space `%8F` this also seems to work.

```html
<a href={`sms:%8F&body=Hey! I just created ${input}`}>
  Invite
</a>
```